# bucle do while en Javascript

Tags: javascript, nodejs, condiciones, while

Tengo este codigo en Javascript que se ejecuta en node el cual tiene como funcion realizar diferentes operaciones sobre un array de objetos. Si la consola me pide el numero e inserto el numero 1 deberia mostrar el array en forma de tabla, si inserto el numero 2 debe mostrar la cantidad de objetos en el array, si inserto el numero 3 debe mostrar por consola los nombres de los alumnos, si inserto el numero 4 debe eliminar el ultimo objeto del array.

He creado un bucle do while, y he anadido condiciones dentro del mismo para cada opcion. Pero no logro que el programa se quede dentro del bucle. Por ejemplo: hay dos objetos al inicio y si yo elimino uno de ellos y luego pido la cantidad de objetos que hay en el array deberia mostrarme solo 1. Pero el programa no se queda dentro del bucle...

Este es mi codigo hasta el momento:

```
import readline from 'readline';

const rl = readline.createInterface({  
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout
});


const students = [{
  age: 32,
  examScores: [],
  gender: 'male',
  name: 'edu'
},
{
  age: 29,
  examScores: [],
  gender: 'female',
  name: 'silvia'
}]

function requirements() {
  console.log('1- Mostrar en formato de tabla todos los alumnos.')
  console.log('2- Mostrar por consola la cantidad de alumnos que hay en clase.')
  console.log('3- Mostrar por consola todos los nombres de los alumnos.')
  console.log('4- Eliminar el último alumno de la clase.')
}
```

Students es el array de objetos. y la funcion requeriments es lo que debo mostrar por consola despues de seleccionar cada opcion.

```
function getNumberFromConsole() {
  const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    rl.question('Introduce el numero: ', (num) => {   
      rl.pause();                                      
      resolve(num)
    })
  })

  return promise;
}

let numberFromConsole;
```

Aqui escribi la funcion para pedir un numero al usuario y la introduje dentro de una promesa, ya que pedir un numero al usuario constituye una funcion asincrona.

```
do {
  numberFromConsole = await getNumberFromConsole() ;

  if (numberFromConsole === '1') {
    console.table(students)
    requirements();
  } else if (numberFromConsole === '2') {
    console.log(students.length)
    requirements();
  } else if (numberFromConsole === '3') {
    names()
    requirements();
  } else if (numberFromConsole === '4') {
    students.pop()
    console.log(students)
    requirements();
  } else {
    console.log('Sorry the game is over')
}
  
} while (numberFromConsole != 0 && numberFromConsole <= '4')  {

}
```

Aqui esta el bucle do while que escribi, al final escribi las dos condiciones para que el programa se salga del bucle que son: que el usuario inserte un 0 o que añada un numero mayor a 4. Lo que necesito es que el programa no se salga del bucle y siga pidiendo numeros al usuario hasta que deje de cumplirse la condicion.

Comment: Cuando haces una pregunta y te responden, se espera que tu tengas la gentileza de marcarla como aceptada si te ha ayudado, y en caso contrario le digas al autor de la respuesta que no resuelve tu problema, así él decide cambiarla, mantenerla o borrarla, lo que ayuda a otros usuarios futuros a encontrar soluciones.

Comment: Vale muchas gracias

Comment: como acepto una respuesta o la rechazo?

Comment: Tienes la condición mal, el bucle se mantiene mientras numberFromConsole es distinto de 0 y mayor que 4. Con 1,2 y 3 se sale

Comment: Si tienes razon tenia la condicion al reves pero la cambie e igual se sale del bucle. Coloque <= 4

Comment: Disculpa si que me funciono muchas gracias... como acepto tu respuesta?

Comment: La respuesta se acepta con el ✓ al lada izquierdo de la respuesta

Comment: ah vale pero entonces creo que no puedo porque es un comentario no una respuesta